# How to isolate part of a line of text in order to use it as a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, version

I'm creating bash script and want to check version number of program from a line in a file and use it to make different checks and operations.

The version line in file is looking like this (examples):

```
Program Version 1.3
```

or

```
Program Version 1.3.1
```

It's on different lines in different versions but always follow the same syntax. How to remove the first part and isolate only the version number in order to put it in a variable?

Comment: Here is what I have used at the end

    Version=`find . -type f -name "filename" -exec grep -h 'Program Version' {} + | awk -F " " '{print $3}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GNU grep` with `-P` for perl-style `regEx` match, and `-o` flag to return only the matching pattern.

```
grep -oP 'Program Version \K[^ ]*' file
1.3.1
```

To save it in a variable

```
versionNo="$(grep -oP 'Program Version \K[^ ]*' file)"
printf "%s\n" "$versionNo"
1.3.1
```

Use `perl` `regEx` itself,

```
perl -lne 'print "$1" if /^Program Version (\d.+)/' file
1.3.1
```

in variable,

```
versionNo="$(perl -lne 'print "$1" if /^Program Version (\d.+)/' file)" file
printf "%s\n" "$versionNo"
1.3.1
```

Using `GNU sed`

```
sed -r 's/Program Version ([[:digit:]].+).*/\1/' file
1.3.1
```

and

```
versionNo="$(sed -r 's/Program Version ([[:digit:]].+).*/\1/' file)" file
printf "%s\n" "$versionNo"
1.3.1
```

Comment: The actual perl example doesn't need `\k` as you are printing a capture group.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you obtain that `Program Version 1.3.1` for example launching some kind of command. Well, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
version=$(yourCommandWhichShowsVersion 2> /dev/null | egrep "^Program Version [0-9]" | awk '{print $3}')
```

Explanation:

- You need to launch the command which show the version
- You redirect the output to egrep which search through all lines matching only which starts `^` <- this is to start string, with the desired text `Program Version`, and this `[0-9]` is to match one number. If you don't know if the version can be 1.3 or 1.3.1 or 1 that's all you need.
- awk is going to "select" the second column (first is "Program version" and second is the version number)

Good luck!

Comment: There is nearly never a reason to pipe the output of `grep` to `awk`. Also, fields are numbered from 1 in `awk`, so you are looking for field 3, not field 2. `awk` can filter its own input. `... | awk '/^Program Version [0-9]/ {print $3}'`.

Comment: Maybe you are right and it can be done only with awk, but this is working! because after "piping" to awk the output has only 2 data columns and it works!! The second one is the version. I tested with some different programs which show its version on help option for example and it worked in all cases. Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: Why would it _not_ print `Version`? Why should there only be two data columns? `awk '{print $2}' <<< 'Program Version 1'` will print `Version`, not `1`.

Comment: Wow, sorry... both of you are right. My mistake... I edited the post. Thank you so much. I put in my tests ProgramVersion without space :O

Comment: I actually used a lot similar command to this one. I will mark this one as most useful because I used similar solution which I find clean and easy. I have used find to find + grep to receive the line with the version that I need and -f in AWK to define field separator to be blank space and with that I have separated the version number from the rest of the results. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Value=$(cat program.txt | grep Program\ Version\ | sed "s/Program \Version\ //g")
```

Just finds Program Version then strip it out with sed.

Edit: Sorry misread. Removed version number

Comment: He said he doesn't know the version number... so 1.3 can't be in the grep.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `grep` and `cut` for this, since the pattern is fixed:

```
# find the first occurrence of the line (-m 1) starting with the pattern (^) and 
# the third field (cut -f3) is the version
# this makes sure we ignore
#   a) multiple occurrences of the pattern, if any
#   b) occurrence of "Program Version" anywhere else on a line
# we make no assumption about the format of the version number
version=$(grep -m 1 "^Program Version " program.txt | cut -f3 -d' ')
if [[ -z $version ]]; then
    # version not specified
    # your exception handler here
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Some possible solutions for the problem:

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) `awk '/Program Version/{print $3}' file.txt`
   [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) `grep -oP "Program Version \K[^ ]*" file.txt`
   [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) `sed -n '/Program Version /s///p' file.txt`
   [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) `perl -lane 'if (/Program Version/) {print $F[2]}' file.txt`

(HTH) Hope This Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have used at the end:

```
Version=`find . -type f -name "filename" -exec grep -h 'Program Version' {} + | awk -F " " '{print $3}'`
```

I have used find + grep to receive the line with the version that I need and -f in awk to define field separator to be blank space and with that I have separated the version number from the rest of the results. Thank you all for your answers.